# Are these graphs homeomorphic?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

[image: 1]

Are these graphs isomorphic, and why?

In advance, thanks!

Comment: Is this really about [graph homeomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism_%28graph_theory%29)? The graphs are actually isomorphic, which is a rather easy way to be homeomorphic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, we can have isomorphism: $a\leftrightarrow v, b\leftrightarrow y, c\leftrightarrow w, d\leftrightarrow x, e\leftrightarrow u$.